# How to track number of data per month and per year?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

My program let's the user indicate if he is a senior or not. I want to generate a report that displays how many users are senior citizen and how many are not, per month and per annum.

Example:

Total users: 20,000

Total seniors registered for the month of february: 1,000

Total seniors registered for the month of..: 1,000

...

Total seniors registered in 2017: 10,000

Is there any other alternative to achieve this without having to create a table in my database for each following years?

Comment: Of course there is. But what does your table look like? And what have you tried? Google for "SQL GROUP BY".

Comment: my table looks something like this in summary: User( name varchar, senior boolean, youth boolean, daycare boolean, dateregistered varchar)

Comment: I may now have an idea. Thank you! @JBNizet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few different groupings here.

Getting the total count is the easiest, as you're just getting the `COUNT` of the entire table:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(`name`) AS `TotalRegistered`
FROM
    `User`;
```

Getting the groupings by month (and year) would be:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(`dateregistered`) AS `Year`,
    MONTH(`dateregistered`) AS `Month`,
    COUNT(`name`) AS `NumberRegistered`
FROM
    `User`
GROUP BY -- Since you want the values counted by year then month
    YEAR(`dateregistered`) AS `Year`,
    MONTH(`dateregistered`) AS `Month`
ORDER BY -- To order the actual results
    YEAR(`dateregistered`) AS `Year`,
    MONTH(`dateregistered`) AS `Month`;
```

As an aside, you should have a primary key that you don't seem to have included here, and your `dateregistered` should be a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` format.